# Java recursion method returns wrong value

Tags: java, recursion

I have a bit of a problem with this recursion method. I'm fairly new to Java.

This method checks if an input is either "exit" only or "start" followed by two times either "user" or "easy".
It works fine except for the return. If I enter a wrong input and then a right on it returns the previous wrong input with which I obviously can't continue working, why is that?

I've had this problem before but always somehow managed to avoid it.

You might notice that I print out a valid commadnd right when it's validated, this works fine and produces the result I need. But when printing out the return of the function on line 2 the above mentioned problem takes place. I've added numbers to the printed strings so I can recognize which is which.

I have tried returning immediately when there's a valid command but I still need that retrun at the end since the function gives me an error if return statements are exclusively in conditional statements so the problem persists.

Thanks for any help!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(setup() + "3");
    }

static String setup() {
        System.out.print("Input command: ");
        String command = input.nextLine();
        String[] split = command.split(" ");
        
        if(!(command.equals("exit") || split.length == 3)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid parameters!");
            setup();
        }
        else {
            if(command.equals("exit")) {
                System.out.println("Valid parameters! Exit");
                System.out.println(command + "2");
            }
            else if(split[0].equals("start") && (split[1].equals("easy") || (split[1].equals("user")) && split[2].equals("easy") || split[2].equals("user"))) {
                System.out.println("Valid parameters! Start");
                System.out.println(command + "1");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid parameters!");
                setup();
            }   
        }
        return command;
    }
```

Comment: Replace `setup();` with `return setup();`

Comment: What is your question? I read your post twice but could not understand what is the expected behaviour/result?

Comment: `setup();` -> `command = setup();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all I think that you meant to call the recusive call as
`return setup()`
second of all when using conditional operator (&&, ||) you should use () for make sure you get the logic condition you expect.
if you will update it to :

- `return setup` instead of `setup()`
- validate what you wrap the right part of condition with Parenthesis():

  `else if (split[0].equals("start") && ((split[1].equals("easy") || split[1].equals("user")) && (split[2].equals("easy") || split[2].equals("user")))) { System.out.println("Valid parameters! Start"); System.out.println(command + "1"); }`